# Wifi on Dell Studio 15

Tags: 10.10, wireless, dell

I have recently updated to ubuntu 10.10 on my Dell Studio 1555

The wifi works perfectly in ubuntu 10.04

but in Ubuntu 10.10 I can't connect at all.

By default I have no wifi at all

System->Administration->Additional Drivers gives two driver options:

```
Broadcom B43 wireless driver
Broadcom STA wireless driver
```

The STA driver shows as disconnected no matter what I do. And doesn't detect any networks.
The B43 driver sees the network but tries to connect forever despite the correct password and Wireless security settings. (I know the password works as I have other computers on the network)

I know the card works because I have windows vista dual booting and it can use the wifi fine.

How can I get my wifi working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by black listing the B43 driver and installing the STA driver.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by utilizing STA driver and WICD instead of the standard Network Manager.